# How to pass the values from different components using React js

Tags: reactjs

I have Three components like Main.js is the parent components Main.js has two different class components like Employee.js and EmployeeAddress.js.

Both components called from Main.js. I can access parent Main.js properties values from Employee.js as well as EmployeeAddress.js.

I want to get the details from Employee.js properties values to EmployeeAddress.js

For ex. I want to display EmployeeName value into EmployeeAddress.js. if modified EmployeeName textbox value from Employee.js

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props)
}
render(){
return(
<Employee />
<EmployeeAddress />
);
}
```

I want to pass values from Employee.js to EmployeeAddress.js
**Note :** Both components are different not having parent and child relationships.

Comment: Either create a parent component for both that has the state you would like to share, or use app-level state management tools like the built-in context api or the 3rd party Redux manager.

Comment: You should consider using contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Main.js:

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state={
    employee : {
       employeeName: '',
       //otherData
    }
  }
}

function handleEmployeeData(data) {
  this.setState({
    employee: data
  })
}

render(){
  return(
    <Employee handleEmployeeData={this.handleEmployeeData} employee={this.state.employee}/>
    <EmployeeAddress handleEmployeeData={this.handleEmployeeData} employee={this.state.employee}/>
   );
}
```

//Employee.js or EmployeeAddress.js

Here set new employee data when `onChange` or `onClick` happens, this will set the employee data in parent state which both children can use

inside these files' render method you can do something like:

```
<NameInput* onBlur={e => this.props.handleEmployeeData({...this.props.employee, name: e.target.value})} />
```

You can do something like this, for any field in employeeData

- Notice `NameInput` is a placeholder you can replace it with any component you want

Comment: May i know how to set the parent (Main.js) values from Employee.js and i want to set the values while changing EmployeeName text field onBlur event.

Comment: See the edited answer. You basically do whatever you would do if the state was on that prop. Just use this.props.instead of this.state since you pass as `props`

Comment: If you are struggling, you can make a codesandbox with your working environment and I will try to help

Comment: Thank you so much @Sinan Yaman after few code changes with your input my scenarios working fine.

Comment: No problem happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You need to to handle the Data in your Main.js and pass it down to the both components. When something is changed you will do it in the parent component and pass it down again

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {

 this.state = {
  employeData: {...}
 }
 constructor(props){
   super(props)
 }

 onChangeName = () =>{
   //changing the name
   this.setState({
    employeData
   })
 }
 
 render(){
  return(
   <Employee {...employeData} onChangeName={this.onChangeName}/>
   <EmployeeAddress {...employeData} onChangeAdress={this.onChangeAdress}/>
  );
}
```

Other options could be a global state management like contextAPI oder redux